# how to uploading Iformfile with other model properties in asp.net core webapi?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi

i am trying to post the file using IFormfile & other property models data in asp.net core web api using swagger but i am getting any way to do both the things(uploading file and other model properties) simultaneously.

please suggest me some good way to do this.

Comment: please update your question with some code and what options/effort you have done so far..

Answer (score 4):

You could create a model that has a string and IFormFile property and use the [FromForm] attribute:

```
public class UploadModel{

    public string Var1 { get; set; }

    public IFormFile File { get; set; }

}
```

In your controller:

```
[HttpPost("/upload")]
public async Task Upload([FromForm] UploadModel model)
{
    if (model.File == null) throw new Exception("File is null");
    if (model.File.Length == 0) throw new Exception("File is empty");
    model.Var1 += "hello world";

    using (Stream stream = file.OpenReadStream())
    {
        using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(stream))
        {
           // Save the file here.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that you can also just have the endpoint params as `IFormFile myFile, [FromForm] specificObjectType otherData`

Comment: This does not work, my file property is null, is there something else that needs to be done?

Comment: Had to add `enctype = "multipart/form-data"` to my form attributes

Answer (score 1):

It could be as following...

```
[HttpPost("/upload/{var1}")]
public async Task Upload(string var1, IFormFile file)
{
    if (file == null) throw new Exception("File is null");
    if (file.Length == 0) throw new Exception("File is empty");

    using (Stream stream = file.OpenReadStream())
    {
        using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(stream))
        {
           // Save the file here.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside a web api you could do as the following -

```
[HttpPost("Data")]
public async Task<IActionResult> postData([FromForm] UploadModal uploadModal)
{
 //getting file from client
 var postedFile = Request.Form.Files[0];

 //then set an Uploads folder
  var upload = path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Uploads");

/*remember you have to create a new folder named "Uploads"(same as 
  above) inside your API folder, this is where all the uploads are going 
  to be stored*/

 //now check if file is empty or not
  if (postedFile.length > 0){
   
  //the below LOC is necessory for handling uploads and downloads 
   inside http requests
  var fileName = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(postedProfile.ContentDisposition).FileName;

  //specify the path to save

  var pathToSave = Path.Combine(Uploads, fileName.ToString());

  //finally create the file using new FileStream() method

  using(var fileStream = new FileStream(pathToSave, FileMode.Create)){
   await postedProfile.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
}
   }
  
  //return a status Ok with details
  return Ok($"Name = {uploadModal.Var1} and fileName = 
  {uploadModal.File}");
}else {
   return BadRequest(new ProblemDetails{Detail = "Failed to 
   Upload"});
 }
```

on doing this your server could give a 500 response, as the [FormForm] attribute is not mapped. TO avoid this do -

```
public class UploadModel{

    public string Var1 { get; set; }
     
    [NotMapped]
    public IFormFile File { get; set; }

}
```

hope that would work for you. I would suggest another solution as well , once I get.